# code to display results in VBA

Tags: sql

I have written the code and on Access 2007, which I would like to display the answer when I run it, but it is not displaying. I think there is a code that I have left out, please help to display.

Code is :

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    Dim rsAsset As Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Asset WHERE Asset.Asset_Condition ='Repairs';"
    Set rsAsset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    Dim Total As Integer
    Total = 0
    rsAsset.MoveFirst
    While (Not rsAsset.EOF)
        Total = Total + rsAsset!Asset_Condition
        rsAsset.MoveNext
    Wend
    Dim Ave As Double
    Ave = Total / rsAsset.RecordCount
    Debug.Print "Total Repairs= " & Total

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    rsAsset.Close
End Sub
```

I have filled the tables with data but do not know how to write a code that will display the answer.

Answer (score 0):

At one point you do `WHERE Asset.Asset_Condition ='Repairs'`, and at another point you threat "Asset_Condition" as if it was a numeric value (`Total = Total + rsAsset!Asset_Condition`).
Now. Is "Asset_Condition" text or number?
And, why not using SQL to do the math instead of going through records 1 by 1 from VBA? Try this guy here, assuming "Asset_RepairCost" is an existing, numeric field in your data table and "Asset_Condition" is text:

```
SELECT SUM(Asset_RepairCost) AS 'TotalRepair', AVG(Asset_RepairCost) AS 'AverageOfTotalRepair' FROM Asset WHERE Asset.Asset_Condition ='Repairs'
```